# Looking for a database creation & management extension for joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm thinking of using joomla to implement a website for my client.

The main objectives are for them to reduce paperwork by entering paper reports into a database, and to start a website for the community to utilize.

Using the Joomla CMS seems like a good fit because it has user levels built in to it.  The customer needs some custom databases that have five levels of access.

1. Full access: Creation, View, Modify, Deletion
2. Creation, View, Modify
3. Creation, View
4. Creation only
5. No access

Additionally, the user that performed an action on the database needs to be recorded for accountability and security auditing purposes.  The levels of access that a user has needs to be easily changeable on a moments notice for such events such as employee demotion, reprimand, or termination.

Another goal for the client is to be able to track which employees have viewed and taken the associated quiz for various training pages.

Is there any suggestions on a joomla extension or combination of extensions that can do this?  If not joomla, is there a different CMS that can accommodate this?  I'd rather not spend the time and bill the not-for-profit agency for all the time it would take for me to write all this by hand if there there has already been extensions like this created somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will any extension in any CMS get exactly what you want. Yeah we have created our own custom component which allows users to create, delete, copy, assign to other users, modify etc & its based on Joomla's Zoo extension. There are many extensions like zoo, seblod in Joomla related to your requirement but it won't fulfill your requirement as it is. So for the extension which fulfill at most of your requirement & customize it as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a look at the Fabrik: https://fabrikar.com/ extension and see if it covers all requirements; if it doesn't you may also pay them to customize it for your needs.

If you'd like to keep on working with non-commercial options, you may opt for a mixed approach.

The "front end" will be marked up by a Joomla website with all of the requirements you may do with it and the core tasks, the ones related to the databases may be accomplished by a database web user interface like nuBuilder: https://www.nubuilder.com/ with its effective support forum.

They are a business open to customizing everything you need; I guess you could get even the availability to ask the realization of a Joomla/nuBuilder extension. The one for WordPress is already available.

Your users will know and access just the Joomla website from which you have to manage with some URLs the connection with custom-developed web database user interface build with nuBuilder.

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and post your questions/answers there so that that community can grow.